# Reload GUI upon selecting a checkbox option

Tags: autohotkey

A simple GUI, containing a text input and a checkbox. If the checkbox is checked, how would you reload the GUI and make the text box disappear?

I want the user to use one option or another but not both.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that you can perform this way:

```
gui, add, text,, this is test
gui, add, checkbox,gcheckthebox vcheckboxvar, this is checkbox
Gui, Add, Edit, vSearch, 
display:
gui, show, w200 h200, Example Window 


Checkthebox:
gui, submit, nohide
If checkboxvar = 1
  {
    GuiControl, Hide, Search
    goto, display
  }
else if checkboxvar = 0
  {
    GuiControl, Show, Search
    goto, display
  }
```